# Get reliable monotonic clock in Java

Tags: java, time

I am using `ThreadMXBean` to get the CPU time of each method, but the problem is that it is not monotonic (the clock value can decrease for a method that actually is executed later). What is the best way to access monotonically increasing CPU time in Java? Note that I have checked `System.nanoTime()`, but from what I understand it also includes the waiting time.

**Update:** The following code shows the problem:

```
public class HelloThread extends Thread {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        HelloThread ht = new HelloThread();
        ht.a(1);
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
    int a(int x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            x = x * 5;
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

I have used aspect-oriented programming (AOP) to get the thread-ids and the CPU-time (which I want to be monotonically increasing). Here's the output in (method name, thread-id, time in milliseconds) format:

```
public static void main(String[]) 1 647.971834
int HelloThread.a(int) 1 1318.913474
void java.io.PrintStream.println(String) 1 1339.034116
End 1 670.156696
```

The AOP code:

```
aspect Profiler {
  pointcut mainStarting(): execution(public static void main(..));
  pointcut mainEnding(): execution(public static void main(..));
  pointcut methodCallBegin(): call(* * (..));
  pointcut methodCallEnd(): call(* * (..));

  static ThreadMXBean threadBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
  double getTime() {
       return (threadBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime() / 1000000.0);
  }
  before(): mainStarting() {
       System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " + getTime());
  }

  after(): mainEnding() {
       System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " + getTime());
  }

   before(): methodCallBegin() {
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " + getTime());
   }
   after(): methodCallEnd() {
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " + getTime());
   }
}
```

I am running this using OpenJDK (java 1.7.0_55) on Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 (6-core processor).

Comment: So, you are calling [`someThreadMXBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getCurrentThreadCpuTime()) in each of your methods, and it returns smaller values for later calls? Are you sure that the methods are executed within the same thread? Have you logged `Thread.currentThread().getId()` together with the clock value output? Ideally, please share some code (an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) which allows us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Andreas, I guess it's possible as thread may migrate to different CPU core which may have independent timers. The `nanoTime()` native implementation on some platforms does some tricks to return non-decreasing values (like check the atomic variable which contains the result of the previous nanoTime call).

Comment: @TagirValeev Its milliseconds.

Comment: @TagirValeev What makes you conclude that there is a problem in the AOP code?

Comment: Can you post the line of your AOP code which does the output? `getCurrentThreadCpuTime()` returns long, how do you get the decimal notation? There must be some additional calculations in your AOP code ... BTW: I am not able to reproduce this with JDK 1.8.0_60 on Windows 7 running on a quad core i5-2520M CPU.  Since this issue might be highly system dependent, you should also add more information about your environment, like CPU type, JDK version and operating system version.

Comment: Because I cannot imagine that `getCurrentThreadCpuTime()` suddenly falls down to half-a-second. Probably I'm wrong. But posting the whole code may make the problem clearer.

Comment: @Andreas: Yes, I divided it by 1_000_000.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you, I will clean the AOP code, and post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the posted aspect does not work as expected. Probably because intercepting every single call is too much (I'm not an expert in AOP). I changed it a little to intercept only `HelloThread.a` and `System.out.println` calls:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean;

aspect Profiler {
  pointcut mainStarting(): execution(public static void main(..));
  pointcut mainEnding(): execution(public static void main(..));
  pointcut methodCallBegin(): (call(* *.a (..)) || call(* *.println (..)));
  pointcut methodCallEnd(): (call(* *.a (..)) || call(* *.println (..)));

  static ThreadMXBean threadBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
  double getTime() {
       return (threadBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime() / 1000000.0);
  }
  before(): mainStarting() {
       System.out.print("mainStarting: "+Thread.currentThread().getId() 
             + " " + getTime()+"\n");
  }

  after(): mainEnding() {
       System.out.print("mainEnding: "+Thread.currentThread().getId() 
             + " " + getTime()+"\n");
  }

  before(): methodCallBegin() {
      System.out.print("methodCallBegin: "+Thread.currentThread().getId() 
             + " " + getTime()+"\n");
  }

  after(): methodCallEnd() {
      System.out.print("methodCallEnd: "+Thread.currentThread().getId() 
             + " " + getTime()+"\n");
  }
}
```

Now the typical result looks like this:

```
mainStarting: 1 93.6006
methodCallBegin: 1 93.6006
methodCallEnd: 1 93.6006
methodCallBegin: 1 93.6006
Hello
methodCallEnd: 1 93.6006
mainEnding: 1 93.6006
```

The result is expected: Such simple code runs so fast, that CPU time counter may not increment at all (at least on Windows platform which may have lower resolution than Linux). Nevertheless such code cannot take 500 ms as displayed in your sample output. It's very fast.

I can make the `a` method slower:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    HelloThread ht = new HelloThread();
    int b = ht.a(1);
    System.out.println("Hello");
}

int a(int x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        x = x * 5;
    }
    return x;
}
```

In this case the results are the following:

```
mainStarting: 1 93.6006
methodCallBegin: 1 93.6006
methodCallEnd: 1 109.2007
methodCallBegin: 1 109.2007
Hello
methodCallEnd: 1 109.2007
mainEnding: 1 109.2007
```

So the `a` call correctly increased the CPU time. No decreases are observed. In general `getCurrentThreadCpuTime()` should not produce significant decreases. Seems that your *original* code differs from the posted one.